# display ms word doc in browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I get my asp.net webpage to display a word document in the browser?  This is a controlled environment where everyone has exactly the same browser settings and everyone uses internet explorer 7.  It is an intranet environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.textcontrol.com/ appears to have some components allowing you to do that. Additionally, you might want to try embedding the document via ActiveX.

Comment: I have tried the ActiveX method and it got a bit messy, so I am now looking for a new solution.  Basically, I know in word you can do a saveas and save the document as html or mht, is it not possible to get .net to do that automatically?  Then display the html file on screen?

Comment: I don't program in windows often, but you might be able to use OLE objects to control it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/?query=word+ole